# Doctrine Many-To-Many delete target entity instead of only jointable record

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have Photo Entity which has Man-To-Many relation with Tag Entity.

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="photos_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="photo_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $tags;
```

Let say that I have a PhotoA which has TagA and TagB. But also I have and PhotoB which also has TagA. When I delete PhotoB, the TagA is also deleted. This is what i DONT want. I define cascade operations as I thought that this should delete only JoinColumn values... but its appears that the TagEntity is also delete as cascade operation.

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="photos_tags",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="photo_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 **/
protected $tags;
```

This annotation solves the problem. I didnt realize that doctrine manage by itself these realtions and remove records in joined table without any need of describe. Obviously if want to delete and Tag Entity, then should annotated cascade operations.